# How to Save or Update values ​of a list in my model correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Tarifa_Sem (models.Model):
    limit_inferior_isr = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    limit_superior = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    cuota_fija_t = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank = True)
    percentage_over_excess = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
 
class Calculator_isr (models.Model):
    rate = models.ForeignKey (Rate_Sem, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name = 'calculators')
    base_gravada = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True)
    limite_inf_calculo = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True)
    percentage_excent_li = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True)
    fixed_ quota = models.DecimalField (max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, null = True, blank = True)
```

I make a query by iterating my values ​​of the base_gravada field.

```
    results = [
        Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter (limite_superior__gte = obj.base_gravada)
        .values_list ('limite_inferior_isr', 'cuota_fija_t', 'percentage_over_excess')
        . First ()
        for obj in Calculadora_isr.objects.all ()
    ]
```

This query returns this list:

```
[(Decimal ('133.22'), Decimal ('2.59'), Decimal ('6.40')),
(Decimal ('8790.96'), Decimal ('1649.34'), Decimal ('30 .00 ')), 
(Decimal ( '2765.43'), Decimal ('292.88'), Decimal ('21 .36 ')), 
(Decimal (' 8790.96 '), Decimal (' 1649.34 '), Decimal ('30 .00'))]
```

To save use the create() method:

```
 

for t in results:
    ... Calculadora_isr.objects.create (limite_inf_calculo = t [0],
     percentage_excent_li = t [2], fixed_ quota = t [1]). Save ()
```

Where I indicate the field and the index of the list to keep, the problem is that it does not save them inside the IDs with the initial values ​​of base_gravated, if not that I create new values:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            Model Calculadora_isr                                   |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|id |base_gravada| limite_inf_calculo  |       fixed_ quota   |  percentage_excent   |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|1  |  1000.00   |                     |                      |                      |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|2  | 10000.00   |                     |                      |                      |
+---+------------+---------------------+----------------------+ ---------------------+
|3  |  5000.00   |                     |                      |                      |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|4  | 10000.00   |                     |                      |                      |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|5  |            |        133.22       |         2.59         |          6.40        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|6  |            |       8790.96       |      1649.34         |         30.00        |
+---+------------+---------------------+----------------------+ ---------------------+
|7  |            |       2765.43       |       292.88         |         21.36        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|8  |            |       8790.96       |      1649.34         |         30.00        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
```

What I need is to be able to save the values ​​in my Calculadora_isr model, which looks like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            Model Calculadora_isr                                   |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|id |base_gravada| limite_inf_calculo  |       fixed_ quota   |  percentage_excent   |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|1  |  1000.00   |       133.22        |           2.59       |          6.40        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|2  | 10000.00   |      8790.96        |        1649.34       |         30.00        |
+---+------------+---------------------+----------------------+ ---------------------+
|3  |  5000.00   |      2765.43        |         292.88       |         21.36        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
|4  | 10000.00   |      8790.96        |        1649.34       |         30.00        |
+---+------------+---------------------+ ---------------------+ ---------------------+
```

I need help with this thank you

Answer (score 0):

during the creation of the `results` list add also the pk's of the instances and later use it to update the instance.

```
results = [
    [obj.id, Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(limite_superior__gte = obj.base_gravada)
    .values_list('limite_inferior_isr', 'cuota_fija_t', 'percentage_sobre_excedente')] for obj in Calculadora_isr.objects.all ()
]
```

---

```
for t in results:
    instance = Calculadora_isr.objects.get(t[0])
    instance.limite_inf_calculo = t[1][0][0]
    instance.percentage_excendente_li = t[1][0][2]
    instance.cuota_fija = t[1][0][1]
    instance.save()
```

Comment: thanks when I execute the code that you indicate me, it gives me the following error:cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: I have tested it locally should work now, try again ;)

Comment: i have this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable,  I think the problem and what I would like to know from the beginning the id that the query generates results

[(6, Decimal ('133.22'), Decimal ('6.40'), Decimal ('2.59'))...
corresponds to the id of the objects of the "Tarifa_Sem" model and to save in my model Calculadora_isr, it should have the ID 1,2,3,4 ...

Comment: Oh, you're right we need here id of `Calculadora_isr` and not of `Tarifa_Sem`. I've updated my answer but this is not the best solution, since there are too many lists inside the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear for me,,, But try something like this.

```
# create list of dicts, to make association between PK's and values (Which represents QuerySet)
results = [
    {obj.pk: Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter (limite_superior__gte=obj.base_gravada).values_list ('limite_inferior_isr', 'cuota_fija_t', 'percentage_sobre_excedente').first()}
    for obj in Calculadora_isr.objects.all ()
]
# iterate over results and find row based on dict key, and update associated row based on dict value
for result in results:
    for k, v in result.items():    
        try:
            get_instance = Calculadora_isr.objects.get(pk=k)   #limite_inf_calculo =t[0],percentage_excendente_li=t[2], cuota_fija=t[1])
            # if model found
            get_instance.limite_inf_calculo = v[0]
            get_instance.percentage_excent_li = v[2]
            get_instance.fixed_quota = v[1]
            get_instance.save()
        except Calculadora_isr.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Also,,, `first()` means that first in `QuerySet` collection, and not first in Database (based on row id). It's better, use `earliest('pk')` instead of `first()` (IMHO). Both are `QuerySet` methods.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: this code return the next error: "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'percentage_sobre_excedente' Thanks for your help

Comment: Change ```percentage_sobre_excedente``` with ```percentage_over_excess```.

Comment: Your ```values_list()``` method was with wrong fields, in your question. Correct it.